# Notification(Alert) comes randomly throughout application in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using selenium webdriver with Java language. I am facing an issue that notification alert appears randomly through out application. Basically these alert have some information as it is functionality .

As script performs its steps but suddenly these alert appears on the screen and my script would fail due to alert message.

**Please give your suggestions, How can we handle this type of alert which appears randomly on any window?**

Below are two points come in my mind to handle this scenario:

1. I will check Alert appears or not at every step (after click or
   other action) but it increases my execution time.
2. Is there any way, we keep monitoring that Alert appears or not. If
       Alert appears just close the Alert if not then keep execute the
       steps of scripts.

Please suggest any workaround to handle such Alert so that our scripts do not fail.

This is the same scenario that we automate mobile application using Appium tool and suddenly any advertisement come on the screen.

It would be good if any one provide java code to handle this type of scenario.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You do not have control over this website,do you? Your first solution seems to be good. Write a class method that checks for alert and turns it off, I doubt it will increase execution time by a lot.

Comment: one simple thing is that place conditional code for visibility of alert in try catch ....

Comment: Can you please check whether there is a way to stop the alerts to occur? Because adding the validation at every step will increase the time and will slow down the application drastically

Answer (score 3):

If you want that unnecessary alert not appear during your `script` execution you can `override` you `alert` **function** before executing your `script` by using `JavaScriptExecutor` as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
executor.executeScript("window.alert = function () { return true}");
```

You can execute this `script` once every time when your page is loaded. this `script` will override your `alert` functionality and the alert will never occur.

I suggest you this script run when if your test is not depend on `alert` because after execute this script the `alert` will not be appear on the page.

other than you can handle `alert` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
```

Now if you want to accept alert, you can use :-

```
alert.accept();
```

and for cancel, you can use :-

```
alert.dismiss();
```

**Note** :- if alert is not present by using `WebDriverWait` it will throw `TimeoutException`.. so you need to handle it.

**Edited..**

For `Appium` automation to solve this problem, you can use a desired capability specifically designed to handle these alerts.

You can either always accept or always dismiss the alerts with these desired capabilities :-

```
autoAcceptAlerts = true
...
capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
```

or

```
autoDismissAlerts = true
...
capabilities.SetCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
```

Furthermore, some of the older versions of `Appium` haven’t worked with this solution, so you might want to try a small workaround with this :-

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

For more info follow [this](http://testdroid.com/news/appium-tip-9-how-to-automatically-dismiss-dialogs-and-autoaccept-alerts)

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thanks for your advice!!    I have one more question I m also automating mobile application using appium. Here also random adv comes on the screen do you have any idea to handle it!!

Comment: you should use `capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);`  for always accept alerts or `capabilities.SetCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);` for always dissmiss alerts..for more info follow this link..http://testdroid.com/news/appium-tip-9-how-to-automatically-dismiss-dialogs-and-autoaccept-alerts.. may be it help..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method wherever you are getting the alert.This method will accept the alert.

```
public void checkAlert(){
            if(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent() != null){
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            }
        }
```